# MySql Workbench sets NOT NULL but then sets DEFAULT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I've been trying to convert my SQL Server DB into a MySql DB. I found out that this can be done by using the MySql Workbench tool.

I follow the steps and when its time to migrate all but 2 Tables fail. Why?

For some reason during the Migration many columns are set NOT NULL but immediately after get a DEFAULT which is NULL, so I get an "invalid default value" error. I don't have the slightest clue why this is happening. Has anybody had to deal with this before?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are these `NOT NULL` columns specified as `NOT NULL` in SQL Server? Or is it only when the migration is made that they are changed from `NULL` to `NOT NULL`?

Comment: @DKyleo They are added when the migration is made :/ If I remove them and press "Apply" it also does nothing.

Comment: That's really odd. Can you provide sorce table from MS SQL Server?

Comment: @MiloszBodzek Added it to the post :)

Comment: Try to manually adjust the Schema. Workbench is full of bugs.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Well later on when it shows you all the tables that failed it gives you the option to alter the SQL and press "Apply". So I altered the SQL, pressed Apply and nothing happened.. The tables were still giving out the errors that were now fixed. Any clue what that could be?